# f# fibbonaci efficient algorithm

Tags: f#, fibonacci

here is 2 functions that calculate the fibbonaci number, they both work correctly, but are written in a different way.

which one would you consider better, more efficient, code more understandable ?

```
let fibe n =
    let rec loop acc1 acc2 n = 
        match n with
        | n when n = 0I -> acc1        
        | x -> loop acc2 (acc1 + acc2) (x - 1I)
    loop 0I 1I n

let myfib n =
    if n = 0I then 0I
    else if n = 1I then 1I
    else
    let rec loop i f s = 
        match i with 
        | x when x = n -> f+s 
        | x when x < n -> loop (i+1I) s (s+f)        
    loop 2I 0I 1I
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talking of clarity, both your functions IMO are unnecessary cluttered and use inadequate language mechanisms for the purpose.

Generating Fibonacci is an ideal fit for expressing via `unfold`, like below:

```
let fibnum n =
    let fibnums = Seq.unfold (fun (current, next) -> 
                Some(current, (next, current+next)))(0I,1I)
    fibnums |> Seq.nth n
```

How may you make it further shorter and clearer?

**UPDATE**: as the question's author considers the ability to operate with Fibonacci members having sequence numbers of `bigint` as important, the above snippet definitely can be adopted to this requirement, although getting less straightforward:

```
let fibnum bigN = 
    let fibnumsI =
        ((0I,0I),(1I,0I))
        |> Seq.unfold (fun ((current, idx), (next, idx)) ->  
            Some((current, idx),((next, idx + 1I), (current+next, idx + 1I))))
    fibnumsI |> Seq.skipWhile (fun (x,i) -> i < bigN) |> Seq.head |> fst
```

Comment: doesn't compile, (n-1I), it asks for 1 instead of 1I

Comment: Sorry, try now, my bad habit to write code without computer :(.

Comment: this way it works with ints only, doesn't work with bigint

Comment: You are wrong, it works with bigints, check the `fibnum` signature `fibnum : int -> System.Numerics.BigInteger`.

Comment: I meant you can't pass it a bigint as a parameter, the ones that I provided are bigint -> bigint

Comment: As Fibonacci numbers grow approximately exponentially on `n`
I'd say for all imaginable purposes `int n` may be good enough.

Comment: is it possible to make it bigint -> bigint ?

Comment: Sure, I've put the alternative version into the answer.

Comment: "Seq.skip (n-1) |> Seq.head" same "Seq.nth (n-1)" and Q:0 origin , A:1 origin

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Agree that missed Seq.nth, updated the answer, thanks.